# Cómo sacar el porcentaje de un valor establecido SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Mi problema es el siguiente: 
Tengo la siguiente query la cual paso un valor establecido, lo que quiero es traer todos los valores alrededor de un 5% a ese valor establecido

Mi query

```
SELECT * 
FROM Mayorizacion3 
WHERE MontoNeto = 50000
```

Por ejemplo: mi valor es 50.000, quiero traer todos los valores alrededor de un 5% de 50.000(osea 2500). Traer todos los valores entre 47.500 hasta 50.000 inclusive.

¿Alguna idea o función que cumpla los requisitos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que sería algo como

```
SELECT * 
FROM Mayorizacion3 
WHERE MontoNeto >= 50000 - (50000 * .05) 
  AND MontoNeto <= 50000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @a NUMERIC = 50000;

SELECT * 
FROM Mayorizacion3 
WHERE MontoNeto BETWEEN (@a- @a*0.05) AND (@a + @a*0.05);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Mayorizacion3 
WHERE MontoNeto >= (MontoNeto - ((50000*5)/100))
AND MontoNeto <= 50000
```

Comment: Ten cuidado con eso. Estás haciendo una *división de enteros* que puede producir resultados inesperados si no conoces su comportamiento.

Comment: No lo sabía.. gracias!